# Why the dynamic part of the fulfillment from index.js is not working?

Tags: javascript, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am using fulfillment from Inline Editor, but when deploying and testing,
don't know why static responses work well but when entering the if's, the default response is 'not available'.
I've checked the diagnostic info, and in fulfillment response, the error is:

```
{
  "error": "conv.parameters is not a function"
}
```

But I don't understand why.

I copy here the code, if you could help me, thank you

```
'use strict';

const functions = require ('firebase-functions');
const {dialogflow} = require ('actions-on-google');

const WELCOME_INTENT = 'Default Welcome Intent';
const FALLBACK_INTENT = 'Default Fallback Intent';
const INFO_DISEASE_INTENT = 'InfoDisease';
const DISEASE_TYPE_ENTITY = 'TypeDisease';


const app = dialogflow ();

app.intent (WELCOME_INTENT, (conv) => {
    conv.ask('Hola! Si quieres puedo darte más información!');
  });


app.intent (FALLBACK_INTENT, (conv) => {
    conv.ask('Ai, no te he entendido, ¿puedes repetirmelo por favor?');
  });

app.intent (INFO_DISEASE_INTENT, (conv) => {

    const disease_type =    
    conv.parameters(DISEASE_TYPE_ENTITY).toLowerCase();

    if (disease_type == "artritis") {
        conv.ask('La artritis es la inflamación de una .');
    } else if (disease_type == "artrosis") {
        conv.ask('Cuando este cartílago, se produce dolor, e.');
    }
      else {
        conv.ask('Me alegra que no tengas ninguna duda!.');
    }

  });


exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely in your line

```
const disease_type =    
conv.parameters(DISEASE_TYPE_ENTITY).toLowerCase();
```

where you are treating `conv.parameters` as a function. The parenthesis in JavaScript are used to indicate that you're trying to call a function.

It looks more like you want to access a property on the `parameters` object with the value of `DISEASE_TYPE_ENTITY`. This is done in JavaScript using square brackets: `[]`

So you probably want to write this as

```
const disease_type =    
conv.parameters[DISEASE_TYPE_ENTITY].toLowerCase();
```